# Gráfico de Barras Agupados no Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Estou trabalhando em um gráfico que envolve um arquivo .csv, minha dúvida é qual seria a melhor maneira de imprimir um gráfico com 3 barras agrupados para cada País/Country que contenha: Median_Wealth, Mean_Wealth e Population. Segue meu código, o que ele está printando e o conteúdo do arquivo CSV:

Código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
  
with open('wealth-per-country.csv', 'r', newline="") as arq:
    reader = csv.reader(arq)
    next(reader)
    for column in csv.reader(arq):
        if column: 
            print(f"Country: {column[0]}, \nMedian_Wealth: {column[1]}, \nMean_Wealth: {column[2]}, \nPopulation: {column[3]}")
```

Printa:

```
Country: Switzerland, 
Median_Wealth: 227,891, 
Mean_Wealth: 564,653, 
Population: 6,866
Country: Australia, 
Median_Wealth: 181,361, 
Mean_Wealth: 386,058, 
Population: 18,655
Country: Iceland, 
Median_Wealth: 165,961, 
Mean_Wealth: 380,868, 
Population: 250
Country: Hong Kong, 
Median_Wealth: 146,887, 
Mean_Wealth: 489,258, 
Population: 6,267
Country: Luxembourg, 
Median_Wealth: 139,789, 
Mean_Wealth: 358,003, 
Population: 461
Country: Belgium, 
Median_Wealth: 117,093, 
Mean_Wealth: 246,135, 
Population: 8,913
Country: New Zealand, 
Median_Wealth: 116,433, 
Mean_Wealth: 304,124, 
Population: 3,525
Country: Japan, 
Median_Wealth: 110,408, 
Mean_Wealth: 238,104, 
Population: 104,963
Country: Canada, 
Median_Wealth: 107,004, 
Mean_Wealth: 294,255, 
Population: 29,136
Country: Ireland, 
Median_Wealth: 104,842, 
Mean_Wealth: 272,310, 
Population: 3,491
```

CSV:

```
Country,Median_Wealth,Mean_Wealth,Population
Switzerland,"227,891","564,653","6,866"
Australia,"181,361","386,058","18,655"
Iceland,"165,961","380,868",250
Hong Kong,"146,887","489,258","6,267"
Luxembourg,"139,789","358,003",461
Belgium,"117,093","246,135","8,913"
New Zealand,"116,433","304,124","3,525"
Japan,"110,408","238,104","104,963"
Canada,"107,004","294,255","29,136"
Ireland,"104,842","272,310","3,491"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando os dados mostrados, eu faria da maneira mais simples possível ...

Dá uma olhada como estou usando o `append` para guardar os devidos dados em listas específicas, estou de maneira rudimentar usando um `replace` para remover a virgula e converter os valores para um `float`, depois de dar as devidas sanitizada nos dados é só criar subplotes de cada var específica com os dados de interesse, óbvio usar o `plt.bar` para plotar em forma de barra, rodando aqui em um versão `python3.3` usei o numpy para linearmente criar os vetores de auxilio do plot, acredito que poderá substituir por outra função equivalente, segue o código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv

country=[]
Population=[]
Median_Wealth=[]
Mean_Wealth=[]

  
with open('stack_csv.csv', 'r', newline="") as arq:
    reader = csv.reader(arq)
    next(reader)
    for column in csv.reader(arq):
        if column: 
            country=np.append(country, column[0])
            column[1]=column[1].replace(',', '.')
            Median_Wealth=np.append(Median_Wealth, column[1])
            column[2]=column[2].replace(',', '.')
            Mean_Wealth=np.append(Mean_Wealth, column[2])
            column[3]=column[3].replace(',', '.')
            Population=np.append(Population, column[3])
            

width = 0.15

x1 = np.arange(len(country))
x2 = [x + width for x in x1]
x3 = [x + width for x in x2]

Median_Wealth = list(map(float, Median_Wealth))
Mean_Wealth = list(map(float, Mean_Wealth))
Population = list(map(float, Population))


fig, ax = plt.subplots()


plt.bar(x1, Median_Wealth, color='blue', width=width, edgecolor='white', label='Median_Wealth')
plt.bar(x2, Mean_Wealth, color='green', width=width, edgecolor='white', label='Mean_Wealth')
plt.bar(x3, Population, color='red', width=width, edgecolor='white', label='Population')

ax.set_ylabel('Valores')
ax.set_title('Agrupados')
ax.set_xticks(x1)
ax.set_xticklabels(country)
ax.legend()

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

O Plot do código acima ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]